# Python: os.system() without return or error

Tags: python, bash, error-handling, system, subprocess

I need to use os.system() a few times in my script, but I don't want errors from the shell to appear in my script's window.  Is there a way to do this?  I guess it's sort of like silent commands, running to their full extent, but not returning *any* text.  I can't use 'try', because it's not a Python error.

Comment: `os.system()` is deprecated. Use the [subprocess library](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redirect the command's standard error away from the terminal. For example:

```
# without redirect
In [2]: os.system('ls xyz')
ls: cannot access xyz: No such file or directory
Out[2]: 512

# with redirect
In [3]: os.system('ls xyz 2> /dev/null')
Out[3]: 512
```

P.S. As pointed out by @Spencer Rathbun, the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module should be preferred over `os.system()`. Among other things, it gives you direct control over the subprocess's stdout and stderr.

Comment: @lucase.62 no- Use `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended way](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) to call a subprocess and manipulate its standard output and standard error is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.  Here is how you can suppress both the standard output and the standard output:

```
import subprocess

# New process, connected to the Python interpreter through pipes:
prog = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
prog.communicate()  # Returns (stdoutdata, stderrdata): stdout and stderr are ignored, here
if prog.returncode:
    raise Exception('program returned error code {0}'.format(prog.returncode))
```

If you want the subprocess to print to standard output, you can simply remove the `stdout=…`.